# ssh can use in bash shell, can't use in shell file

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, amazon-ec2

I use ssh to login EC2(Amazon)

```
ssh -i /home/XXX/mykey.pem ec2-user@ec2-NN-NNN-NN-NN.us-foo-N.compute.amazonaws.com
```

It success,but when I write the command to the file like this:

login.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
ssh -i  /home/XXX/mykey.pem ec2-user@ec2-NN-NNN-NN-NN.us-foo-N.compute.amazonaws.com
```

after `chmod +x login.sh`
I run the script, it return:
`ssh: Could not resolve hostname`

So how to solve it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two likely reasons:

1. You have a typo in the hostname in the script.
2. The script has a CRLF instead of LF as the line ending on the `ssh` line. This often happens when you edit the file on a Windows system and transfer it to Unix. Use `dos2unix` to fix the script.